# Independence of iid samples when function is applied to to one member of sample

Tags: independence

I have tuples, $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$, which are iid.

Suppose I introduce a new variable, $T_i = g(X_i)$, where the function $g$ is arbitrary. Is it true that $\{(T_i, Y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ are iid as well? Is the following argument correct?

---

My reasoning:

for $i \neq j$:

\begin{align*}
P(T_i \in A, Y_i \in B, T_j \in C, Y_j \in D) &= P(g(X_i) \in A, Y_i \in B, g(X_j) \in C, Y_j \in D) \\
&= P(X_i \in g^{-1}(A), Y_i \in B, X_j \in g^{-1}(C), Y_j \in D) \\
&= P(X_i \in g^{-1}(A), Y_i \in B) P(X_j \in g^{-1}(C), Y_j \in D) \\
\end{align*}

where $g^{-1}(A) = \{ x: g(x) \in A \}$.

Comment: Yes, if $Y$ and $X$ are independent, then so are $Y$ and $g(X)$.  This makes sense intuitively since the function $g$ itself doesn't carry any information about $Y$, so merely applying that function to $X$ can't somehow induce dependence.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I just needed some reassurance. Thanks.

Comment: What _exactly_ is meant by iid when you say that $(X_i,Y_i)$ are iid? Are the $2n$ random variables a collection of mutually independent identically distributed random variabes? Are the $n$ _pairs_ $(X_i,Y_i)$ identically distributed and independent of each other? (nothing being implied about the independence of $X_i$ and $Y_i$?)

Comment: @DilipSarwate, The last one: $i\neq j \Rightarrow P(X_i,Y_i,X_j,Y_j) = P(X_i, Y_i) P(X_j,Y_j)$. I should've been more precise in my statement.

Comment: "iid" means *identical* and independently distributed.  Obviously the first "i" no longer holds upon applying $g$ to just one component.  The remaining "i" is addressed even more generally in the duplicate, which is applied here by transforming one variable with $g$ and the other with the identity transformation.

Comment: @whuber, what I mean is that each $(g(X_i), Y_i)$ have the same distribution, $i=1,\ldots,n$. You're saying that's not the case? I don't see how that could be.

Comment: I see what you mean, and you're right: the $(g(X_i),Y_i)$ are indeed identically distributed when the $(X_i,Y_i)$ are.  The question of independence is whether $g(X_i)$ is independent of $g(X_j)$ for $i\ne j$. That is a special (simpler case) of the question answered by the duplicate, which asks whether $g(X_i)$ and $h(X_j)$ would be independent for any transformations $g$ and $h$.